# Yet another issue about log4net 1.2.11 conflicts

Tags: c#, log4net, gac

I've spent the last 2 hours looking over these issues on SO, and nothing seems to be working.

I have a solution that uses log4net 1.2.11, via NuGet.  It works fine on my 32 bit development workstation running Windows 7.  It does not run on my 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 test system.  The error I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies.  The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I am looking in the application directory on my test system.  The `log4net.dll` file there is version 1.2.11.

The version in the GAC was version 1.2.10.  I have removed it.  There was a version on my development server that was yet again something else; I removed that as well.  I have rebuilt; I have redeployed.  I have added

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669E0DDF0BB1AA2A" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.10.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

to my configuration file.  Nothing seems to make a bit of difference.  My deployment project shows the right version and signature of the log4net assembly that is being deployed.

I do not know what else I can do, but I am getting quite frustrated that a logging library is preventing my application from running.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here was my solution: I changed from log4net to Common.Logging to NLog.  It didn't take a lot of effort, and I don't think it should have been necessary, but it worked, and worked well.

Comment: I had to do the same thing.  The problem is when dependencies require conflicting versions of log4net.

Comment: See @keithl8041's answer for an actual solution to this problem rather than a work around. :)

Comment: @JohnySkovdal, actually I would call that a workaround as well.  That means you have to continue using a deprecated library and an old library key with a clear EOL.  That limits your options in the future.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Not the way I understand it. It's something to use until your other dependencies gets up to speed. For now, the latest version is available with both keys, so that solution only a uses deprecated key, not a deprecated library.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal I think we're looking at it from different angles, but Common.Logging allowed me to completely ignore an extraordinarily poor design/ implementation decision by our friends at apache, without worrying about about waiting for everyone to catch up.  This was a quick and painless alternative that circumvented the problem entirely.  I have adopted this in all my applications now, and it just works.  I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue after upgrading log4net through NuGet, only to find that the newer version was signed with a different key. Sigh. For some reason this only became apparent when I deployed to the live server, it didn't crop up in development.

You can grab the 'oldkey' version from [the apache log4net site](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi). Just nuke your references from the project file and reference the oldkey version instead.

Answer (score 3):

We are having the exact same issue. A dependency deep in the code base is putting 1.2.10 into the GAC and NuGet is trying to use 1.2.11. We gave up using NuGet for log4net, too much of a headache. Seems NuGet is a bit all or nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you have to really drill down into the project dependencies. In my case it was a reference of a reference of the actual Service Stack project that was referencing a different version of Log4Net.

To fix it I added the newest version of Log4Net from nuget to the ServiceStack project. I also made sure the direct reference was using the newest version and this solved the issue.

You can use a dependency tool to quickly find which references are using conflicting versions, but if you don't have a tool for this you can just compile the project's reference by itself and see what version of log4net.dll gets copied to the directory.